# how to display data from json with ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs

So i loaded the json and now i cant display it and it says not well-formed. But i'm not really sure what to write in html.

here is my js:

```
app.controller('jsonController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('podaci.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.gradovi = data;
    });
});
```

and html:

```
<div ng-controller = "jsonController">
   <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="gradovi in ponudjene">
         {{gradovi.ponudjene}}
      </li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

and this is json:

```
{
   "ponudjene": [
      "Ada",
      "Adaševci",
      "Žitni Potok",
      "Žitorađa",
      "Zlatibor",
      "Zlatica",
      "Zlodol",
      "Zlot",
      "Zmajevo",
      "Zminjak",
      "Zrenjanin",
      "Zubin Potok",
      "Žuč",
      "Zuce",
      "Zvečan",
      "Zvezdan",
      "Zvonce",
      "Đala",
      "Đunis",
      "Đurđevo",
      "Đurđin"
   ],
   "tacno": [
      "Zvezdan",
      "Zvezdan",
      "Bor",
      "Rudna Glava",
      "Majdanpek"
   ],
   "vreme": 100,
   "oblast": "Istocna srbija"
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the json you are getting is not in proper json format. So you won't be able to output it. I would start by debugging the json you are getting to make sure it is correct

Comment: `ponudj in gradovi.ponudjene` ?

Comment: But is there a way to display all items in "ponudjene" somehow without changing json file?

Comment: @Branka `<li ng-repeat="ponudj in gradovi.ponudjene">
 {{ponudj }}
 </li>`

Comment: @Branka, yes you can, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
<ol>
   <li ng-repeat="item in gradovi.ponudjene">
      {{item}}
   </li>
   <li ng-repeat="item in gradovi.tacno">
      {{item}}
   </li>
   <li>
      {{gradovi.vreme}}
   </li>
   <li>
      {{gradovi.oblast}}
   </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your json data looks like, but your $scope is "gradovi", so your li should look something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in gradovi">
     {{item.name_of_field_in_your_json}}
</li>
```

UPDATE:

Now that I see your json data.  Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/778/

Answer (score 0):

Found it!Thank u all for help! :)

```
<ol>
<li ng-repeat="item in gradovi.ponudjene track by $index">
 {{item}}
</li>
</ol>
```